# Redshift Snapshot using Redshift Manager by triggering Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

How to create all prod redshift snapshots using Redshift Manager...
action: aws:invokeLambdaFunction using this method (invoking Lambda Function) i want to create redshift cluster snapshots.

Comment: action: aws:invokeLambdaFunction using such commands can we take snapshots of all redshift clusters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my friends helped me with the Solution.

1. we need to allow the Invoke function as shown below.

- PolicyName: AllowInvokeLambdaPolicy
  PolicyDocument:
  Version: "2012-10-17"
  Statement:
  - Effect: Allow
  Action:
  - lambda:InvokeFunction

2. We created a script to run via the Lambda function which collects the Cluster Name and invokes Lambda.

- name: BackupRedshiftCluster
  action: aws:invokeLambdaFunction
  maxAttempts: 3
  inputs:
  FunctionName: !Sub redshift-manager
  Payload: !Sub |
  {
  "action": "snapshot",
  "cluster": "{{FetchClientName.ClientName}}"",
  "snapshot_suffix": "{{GenerateUniqueSnapshot.UniqueString}}"",
  "snapshot_retention": "15"
  }